# Tests of independence for 2 and more samples

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, regression, python

I need your help.
Almost every theorem from probability theory, mathematical statistics requires an independence of 2 and more random variables, also samples. There are some tests (that check independence of 2 or more samples) on categorical data, but I do not see such tests for samples contain numbers etc i.e. not categorical data. Please, could you provide this information about these tests, thanks a lot.

Comment: 1) Hi gregory, to get useful responses please add more information like what are you looking for and what you have attempted, where you are stuck.
2) "but I do not see such tests for samples contain numbers ". I don't understanding this statement. can you pls clarify?

Comment: Maybe you do not know the statement of Central Limit Theorem, for example?

Comment: A thank you for your comments would have been just fine. (Please don't be rude in replying to comments, especially those that are trying to help you: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/591/439353)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/how-do-i-test-that-two-continuous-variables-are-independent (apologies in advance if my comment is weird or if i did not study probability theory at all.)

Comment: Ok, thank you, there is a lot information in you post and post’s comments. It could be helpful

Comment: What do you think if to test this directly: F(x,y) = F(x) * F(y), where F = N(0,1). For my samples I used Jarque Bera test and proofed on significant level that x, y ~ N(0,1)